# Nrwl: Storybook giving me error TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Tags: nrwl-nx, angular-storybook

My Angular storybook was working perfectly fine, but i added a compoenent, tried to re-generate storybook and started getting followoing error

```
    info => Loading presets

info => Loading 1 config file in "C:\code\libs\lib-core\.storybook"
info => Loading 8 other files in "C:\code\libs\lib-core\.storybook"
info => Adding stories defined in "C:\code\libs\lib-core\.storybook\main.js"
info => Found custom tsconfig.json
info => Using implicit CSS loaders
info => Loading angular-cli config
info => Using angular project "lib-core:build" for configuring Storybook
ERR! => Could not get angular cli webpack config
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined


          Broken build, fix the error above.
          You may need to refresh the browser.


———————————————————————————————————————————————

>  NX   

  Failed tasks:


  Hint: run the command with --verbose for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, i had to add a property tsConfig under architect --> build --> options, and try to re-run storybook

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I updated my packages by running `yarn` (or `npm install`) and it worked for me.